# What is HttpWebRequest uri for the following POST

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I attempting to POST data to the following using HttpWebRequest. However I am not sure what the URI should be for the following task

```
POST /v1/session  
Host: developer.messenger.yahooapis.com    
Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials >    
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8  
Content-Length: 38    
{        
  "presenceState" : 0,      
  "presenceMessage" : "I am now logged in"   
}
```

I have something like this

```
string uri = "https://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/session  ";
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Is that uri correct for the required post.

Comment: Yes, although it's not possible to deduce the scheme from the info you provide.

Comment: Yes [filler is: You could have tested it and using a tool like fiddler see that it works :)]